# Show that a polynomial family is a base to a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

QUESTION

Taking $P4 = ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ the vector space of polynomials of degree $4$ or lower and $H$ the subspace of $P_4$ such that its elements satisfy the conditions $p(1)= 0$, $p(-1)=0$

Show that $B = \{q_1,q_2,q_3\}$ is a base of $H$ if the polynomials are the following:

$q_1(x) = x^2-1$

$q_2(x)=x^3-x$

$q_3(x) = (x^2-1)^2$

ANSWER ?

So I know that to be a base you need to be linearly independent and you have to generate $P_4$ (in this specific case). 
To prove so, I tried to calculate the matrix of the canonical coordinates of $B$, which gave me
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
1&0&-2\\
0&-1&0\\
-1&0&1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then I used Gaussian elimination and got to the following point (I had to transform $(x^2-1)^2$ into $x^4-2x^2+1$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-1&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$$
But I am stuck because how can I show that $B$ is a base of $H$ if $\dim(B) = 3$.
It should be $5$? I recall reading that to be a base of something, you need to have the same dimension.

Comment: Work on the formatting, it is not possible to understand what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that the number of elements in the basis must equal the dimension of the space. You are asked to show that $\{q_1,q_2,q_3\}$ is a basis for $H$, not for $P_4$, so you should verify that

1. The space $H$ is $3$-dimensional.
2. The basis elements $q_1$, $q_2$ and $q_3$ are contained in $H$.
3. The basis elements $q_1$, $q_2$ and $q_3$ span $H$.

For the latter, it suffices to show that $q_1$, $q_2$ and $q_3$ are linearly independent.

1. The space $P_4$ is $5$-dimensional, and $H\subset P_4$ is defined as
   the subspace of polynomials $p\in P_4$ satisfying $p(1)=p(-1)=0$, or
   equivalently the $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e\in P_4$ satisfying
   $$a+b+c+d+e=0\qquad\text{ and}\qquad a-b+c-d+e=0.$$ These are two
   (inequivalent) linear equations, so $H$ is indeed $3$ dimensional,
   not $5$-dimensional!
2. It is easily verified that $q_1,q_2,q_3\in H$ by plugging in $1$ and
   $-1$.
3. Your Gaussian elimination yields a matrix of rank $3$, which means that its column vectors $q_1$, $q_2$ and $q_3$ span a $3$-dimensional space. So they span all of $H$.

Alternatively, you could argue that $q_1$, $q_2$ and $q_3$ are linearly independent along the following lines: Because $q_1$ and $q_2$ have different degrees they are certainly not scalar multiples of eachother, so they are linearly independent. Any linear combination of $q_1$ and $q_2$ has degree at most $3$, whereas $q_3$ has degree $4$, so $q_3$ is linearly independent of $q_1$ and $q_2$, and we are done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just one question : You say we have 2 equations so dim H = 3, and not 5. I thought the dim H was dependant of the number of variables (a,b,c,d,e). This is why I am confused. What allows you to say that H is 3 dimensional?

Comment: Good question! Every linear equation effectively eliminates one variable; for example the first one tells us that $a=-b-c-d-e$ and the second then tells us that
$$b=a+c-d+e=(-b-c-d-e)+c-d+e=-b-2d,$$
or equivalently that $b=-d$. So that leaves $3$ free variables $c$, $d$ and $e$, so $H$ is $3$-dimensional.

Note that you should be careful that each equation really does eliminate a variable; for example taking the same equation twice won't eliminate any more variables the second time.

Comment: As a side note; another way to see that $H$ is $3$-dimensional is to use the fact that if $p(1)=p(-1)=0$, then $p$ is divisble by $x-1$ and $x+1$, and hence
$$p(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(ax^2+bx+c),$$
for some scalars $a$, $b$ and $c$, because the degree of $p$ is at most $4$. But the perspective of 'equations eliminating variables' is much more broadly applicable, and is an insightful one to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Note that given the conditions $p(1)=p(-1)=0$, it follows that $H$ is the subspace of $P_4$ consisting of all fourth degree polynomials divisible by both $x-1$ and $x+1$ and therefore by $x^2-1$. Using the division algorithm we know that for all $p(x)\in P_4$
\begin{eqnarray}
p(x)&=&ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e\\
    &=&[ax^2+bx+(a+c)](x^2-1)+(b+d)x+(a+c+e)
\end{eqnarray}

so we know that for $p(x)\in H$ the remainder must be zero.

Thus $d=-b$ and $e=-(a+c)$ and every element of $H$ can therefore be expressed in the form

\begin{eqnarray}
p(x)&=&ax^4+bx^3+cx^2-bx-(a+c)\\
    &=&a(x^4-1)+b(x^3-x)+c(x^2-1) \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

So we know that $B^\prime=\{x^4-1,x^3-x,x^2-1\}\,$ forms a basis for $H$. But we want $(x^2-1)^2=x^4-2x^2+1$, not $x^4-1$. But if in equation $(1)$ we let $a=1,\,b=0,\,c=-2\,$ we get

\begin{equation}
 1\cdot(x^4-1)+0\cdot(x^3-x)-2\cdot(x^2-1)=(x^2-1)^2
\end{equation}

Since $(x^2-1)^2$ is a linear combination of the elements of $B^\prime\,$ we may substitute it in place of $x^4-1$ in $B^\prime$ to get the desired basis $B$.